# No prompt ubuntu virtual machine using vagrant on Git Bash

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, git-bash

After logging into the VM using `vagrant ssh` using GitBash on Windows 10, I don't see any directory prompts. While it does run the python web forum (for a tutorial on Udacity on [Intro to Relational Databases](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-relational-databases--ud197)), it won't let me run `psql` so I can continue the lesson. I can change directories, list information about the files, and run python but the prompt isn't working like normal.

Screenshot here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEGfA.png).

Please note the forum is running, this screenshot was taken after I exited and restarted vagrant.

Vagrant version 1.9.6

Ubuntu version 16.04.2 LTS

All programs installed or running in administrator mode.

Comment: Having the same issue myself. You can use the windows cmd and you can see the prompt again. Not a proper solution but its what I'm using for now until I can find a fix for git bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get Git Bash to work, but the show window for the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager does work just fine. I've been using Git Bash to start the VM, then switch to the Oracle VM UI window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem attempting to set up [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) - in my case it seems to be an issue with Git Bash / MINGW64.

My work-around was to use PuTTY

- Install PuTTY, PuTTYgen
- Create a .ppk of the key you're using to connect to the vagrant vm by loading the private key in PuTTYgen and saving the private key
- Create a new PuTTY session with your vagrant details, in my case I just copied what was displayed after running "vagrant up" as far as SSH address, username (my PuTTY session Host Name would be "vagrant@localhost" port: 2222)
- specify the ppk in the PuTTY configuration under Connection-> SSH-> Auth-> Private key for authentication

In short, try connecting with PuTTY or some other terminal emulator and see if you have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with truing to connect to a virtual Homestead session (Laravel) using virtual box and I was trying to connect via Gitbash MINGW64 as well.

I tried the same in cmd.exe (command: vagrant ssh) and it worked.

So should be issue with Git bash.